# Force application restart to specific activity

Tags: android, android-activity

In my application I want to force restart to happen only from the first activity.

However, I don't want this to happen when the user clicked "Home" and then went back to the application.

I want it to happen when Android killed the application due to memory shortage.
In this case, instead of starting the last-running activity I want it to start back from the first one.

At the moment what happens is that if the application is killed then on return it tries to go back to the last activity.

This is what appears in the Logcat:

```
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.applicat.meuchedet/.UpdateMemberDetailsScreen (has extras) } from pid 22161
Displayed com.applicat.meuchedet/.UpdateMemberDetailsScreen: +1s468ms
Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{40824f20 com.applicat.meuchedet/.UpdateMemberDetailsScreen}
Process com.applicat.meuchedet (pid 22161) has died.
Start proc com.applicat.meuchedet for activity com.applicat.meuchedet/.UpdateMemberDetailsScreen: pid=22735 uid=10025 gids={3003}
```

UpdateMemberDetailsScreen is the activity I am talking about.
After the second row above I run a heavy application (Words with Friends :)).
So, mine exits and then dies.

When it restarts it goes back to the one that was running at the time it died.

Comment: That's kind of odd.  When an 'OutOfMemoryError' occurs it shouldn't reload the last Activity.  Are you sure that you are not catching the memory error and performing something else other than exiting out?  When it happens with loaded Bitmap with me, it has always crashed and then brought me back to the splash screen for a restart on the application.

Comment: I am definitely not catching it. To be sure that that is happening I connect my phone to my computer and can see in the DDMS that it definitely "disappearing" when I load another application. It then comes back as soon as I exit the new one. 
I know it is coming back to that activity because I am getting a NullPointerException in that activity.

Comment: Post the code from `UpdateMemberDetailsScreen.onPause()`